# Need help understanding algebra steps taken in proof of why an even minus an odd is odd

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I don't understand the algebra used in the below example proof from my textbook.  Where does the + 1 come from?  Is it okay to just add 1 anywhere you want?  Or is there some rule here or reason you can?

[image]

Comment: $2r - 2s - 1 = 2r - 2s - 2 + 1 = 2(r - s - 1) + 1$

Answer (score 2):

$$2r-2s-1=2r-2s-1-1+1=2r-2s-2+1=2(r-s-1)+1$$

You can subtract 1 and plus 1 to balance things up. Something like adding zero, hence you preserve the equality.

Comment: Ahhh...that makes complete sense!  Thanks for your example!